# Can I select a set of averages in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Can I select a set of averages based on fields in SQL? 
Something like:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(Salary WHERE department = 1) as AvgDept1,
    AVG(Salary WHERE title = 1) as AvgTitle1,
    AVG(TimeOnJob WHERE title = 1 and department = 1) as AvgTime1
FROM
    Employees
```

I understand this is similar to AVG with a GROUP BY but I can't wrap my head around how to get the three values from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like three separate queries,
if you want them bundled into one select you can do something like:

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT AVG(Salary) WHERE department = 1 FROM Employees) AS AvgDept1,
   (SELECT AVG(Salary)  WHERE title = 1 FROM Employees) AS AvgTitle1
   (select AVG(TimeOnJob) WHERE title = 1 and department = 1 FROM Employees) AS AvgTime1
```

Comment: Okay that's sort of what I figured but I wasn't sure how to lump it into one select, I'm trying to lower the number of go-betweens.

Comment: Sure, no problem. In this case this is the easiest more straightforward way to do it, and in SQL Server you don't even have to put a where clause there. You have to remember that when you use a subquery in the select clasuse it must return only one value.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.